# RouteCreationException but I can't find the error

Tags: asp.net, routes

I'm working on a project in Microsoft ASP.NET Core and it threw a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCreationException but I'm not sure why, I think my formatting is all correct. Any ideas? My route:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "results",
                    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Results}/{action=Index}/{cat?}/{sorton?}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
```

Oh and here's the controller it maps to:

```
namespace Uplift.Controllers
{
    [Area("Customer")]
    public class ResultsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ResultsController> _logger;

        public ResultsController(ILogger<ResultsController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(string id, string cat, string sorton)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have fixed it, I'm not sure exactly how but rebuilding my project seemed to do the trick. I also changed around the order of the IActionResults Index() method parameters to match the MapRoute pattern